# Pandas - Check if two dates are the same with determined conditions (2 more variables) and perform actions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

new to pandas, I have a challenge regard checking values and performing multiple actions based on four variables (reception_date,final_date,Status,ID) the problem has the following table:

```
      id             user_email reception_date   end_date    status
0  42872     judahena@ia.com.co      3/30/2022  3/30/2022  Accepted
1  42872   vanvalen@etst.com.co       3/1/2022   3/4/2022  Returned
2  42872  luaquint@maila.com.co       3/7/2022  3/30/2022  In Study
3  99999                a@a.com       3/6/2022  3/28/2022  In Study
4  42872           test@test.es      3/23/2022  3/25/2022  In Study
5  99999                 a@b.es      3/28/2022   4/5/2022  Accepted
6  78787                 a@b.es      3/15/2022  3/16/2022  In Study
```

Firstly, it is required to perform operations for the same ID, (in this example only few are found, however, the database consists of more than 50,000 data), check if in the Status column contains "Accepted", once verified this, check if the "end_date" of the status "In Study" is equal to the "reception_date" of the status "Accepted", if this condition is true, change the status from "In Study" to "Accepted", the expected output would be as follows:

```
      id             user_email reception_date   end_date    status
0  42872     judahena@ia.com.co      3/30/2022  3/30/2022  Accepted
1  42872   vanvalen@etst.com.co       3/1/2022   3/4/2022  Returned
2  42872  luaquint@maila.com.co       3/7/2022  3/30/2022  Accepted
3  99999                a@a.com       3/6/2022  3/28/2022  Accepted
4  42872           test@test.es      3/23/2022  3/25/2022  In Study
5  99999                 a@b.es      3/28/2022   4/5/2022  Accepted
6  78787                 a@b.es      3/15/2022  3/16/2022  In Study
```

Since I'm relative new to pandas I've tried several methods, one of them being my last attemp,using

```
Test=Test.merge(Test.loc[Test.status== 'Accepted'], how='left', left_on=['id'], right_on=['id'], suffixes=("", "_y"))\
.assign(status=lambda x:np.where((x.end_date_y==x.reception_date) & (x.status== 'In Study'), 'Accepted',x.status))
```

However the result of this wasn't the expected output, I hope you can help me with this, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# which rows are Accepted?
m1 = df['status'].eq('Accepted')

# which rows are In Study?
m2 = df['status'].eq('In Study')

# get In Study indices that also have an Accepted
# on the same date
to_change = (df[m2]
 .reset_index()
 .merge(df[m1],
        left_on=['id', 'end_date'],
        right_on=['id', 'reception_date'])
 ['index']
)
# [2, 3]

# update in place
df.loc[to_change, 'status'] = 'Accepted'
```

output:

```
      id             user_email reception_date   end_date    status
0  42872     judahena@ia.com.co      3/30/2022  3/30/2022  Accepted
1  42872   vanvalen@etst.com.co       3/1/2022   3/4/2022  Returned
2  42872  luaquint@maila.com.co       3/7/2022  3/30/2022  Accepted
3  99999                a@a.com       3/6/2022  3/28/2022  Accepted
4  42872           test@test.es      3/23/2022  3/25/2022  In Study
5  99999                 a@b.es      3/28/2022   4/5/2022  Accepted
6  78787                 a@b.es      3/15/2022  3/16/2022  In Study
```

Comment: Wonderful!, this worked extremelly well, thanks for the fast responde as well!